# Empty JSON Objects

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have few columns in my data that are encoded in JSON format. I am trying to convert this data into several columns in `python pandas dataframe`.I have if problems with the empty JSON objects it's not letting me use the JSON.loads function to decode the JSON to several columns.

Here is my code:

```
json_columns = ['customDimensions','device','geoNetwork','hits','totals','trafficSource']

for json in json_columns:
    if df[json][0].startswith('['):
        df[json] = df[json].apply(lambda x: x[1:-1])
        df[json] = df[json].apply(lambda x: x.replace('\'',"\""))
    
    json_load = df[json].apply(loads)
    json_list = list(json_load)
    json_data = dumps(json_list)
    df = df.join(pd.read_json(json_data))
    df = df.drop(json,axis=1)
```

Here are some examples:

```
"customDimensions": [], "customMetrics": [],  "customVariables": [],"experiment": []
```

I want these empty object to return NULL when it gets decoded into a pandas data frame. `hits` columns has the above empty JSON object which is resulting in the below error.

`JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 79 (char 78)`

I have shared a sample from my source data frame. Just in case if anyone needs to have a look at it.
URL: https://drive.google.com/file/d/142tOk03WxxPF30xE9G_UtJ2j0KbpHWc4/view?usp=sharing

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide fraction of the dataframe it self and the code that fails so we can debug it locally? (:

Comment: Here you go: https://drive.google.com/file/d/142tOk03WxxPF30xE9G_UtJ2j0KbpHWc4/view?usp=sharing